# -u does not work in the sort command

Tags: bash

I used this command to sort the file based on the column one and removing the duplicated line in the first column:

```
sort  -t" " -k1 -u
```

But it does not work?

Comment: -u considers the WHOLE line, it won't look at just a single column

Comment: How can I remove the duplicate lines?

Comment: If the whole line is not the same, just the first column, what do you propose to do with the other lines? Which line do you want to choose? The first line?

Comment: To remove duplicate lines, pipe through `uniq -d`.  However that only works if the whole line is duplicated.  To remove duplicates based on a single field will require more work, you might be better off using Perl.

Comment: @MarcB: Despite the upvotes on your comment, it is not correct. The problem is that `-k1` is redundant as it says to sort from the first field to the last. `-k1,1` is what was wanted. Please consider removing your comment as it is incorrect, but cannot be downvoted. (I am referring to GNU sort as the question is tagged `bash`, which is GNU).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU sort does not consider the whole line with `-u` as other's have answered. It will consider the fields that are used to sort on.

In your case you are sorting on *all* the fields as `-k` with one field number says which field to start sorting on. With two numbers, you can also specify the end field.

Try:

```
sort -t" " -k1,1 -u
```

That limits the sorting to sort only on the first field and no others. Uniqueness will be checked only on that field.

To use @Shawn Chin's test file:

```
$ cat in.txt
1 2 3 4
3 4 4 4
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
$ sort -k1,1 -u in.txt
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 4 4
$ sort -k2,2 -u in.txt
1 2 3 4
1 3 4 5
3 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  my original suggestion used an associative array, but then I saw @Shawn Chin's answer and realised I was being over complicated.  Here is Shawn's solution using bash:

```
while read field1 theRest
do
    if [[ $prev != $field1 ]]
    then
        echo "$field1 $theRest"
        prev=$field1
    fi
done < <(sort -t" " -k1 gash.txt)
```